# C error using the function atof, changing a string to a double

Tags: c, atoi, atof

I´m learning to use these functions that change a string to an int or double, but atof doesn´t work for me.

```
char cadena[20]="3.1416";
double x=atof(cadena);
printf("%g",x);
```

I have this simple code, but the output of x is 7.73471e+006. 
Why? Atoi works fine. I´m using mingw compiler, if that could be the error.

Comment: What is your locale? What about `char cadena[20]="3,1416";`? Try adding `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`.

Comment: You probably didn't include `<stdlib.h>`, where `aotf` is declared, so the compiler makes the wrong assumprions about the involved types. Turn on warnings to get notified about missing prototypes.